# c# winforms - how to access ParentForm from ChildForm

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I readed manu articles about this, but - still confused.

from Form1 I open Form2:

```
new Form2().Show();
```

On Form2.ClosingEvent I need:

```
Form1.TextBox1.Visible = false;
```

What code and exactly where should I put - to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that, the way your code is currently structured, your instance of the `Form2` class knows nothing about your instance of the `Form1` class. Therefore, it cannot access properties or call methods on the other object. Remember that `Form1` and `Form2` are the names of ***classes***, not *objects*.

The hacky solution would be to add a public field to your `Form2` class that holds a reference to your `Form1` object. You would fill in that field after you create an instance of your `Form2` class, but before you call the `Show` method.

The next problem you'll run into is that, by default, controls on a form are `private`, which means that only code inside of the class that defines the form can access them. They cannot be accessed or manipulated from code inside of a *different* class.

The design you have is fundamentally broken from an object-oriented perspective. One class should not be manipulating or accessing private members of another class.

If anything, you should be handling this all in `Form1`. Modify the `Form2` class to raise an event when it gets closed, and then subscribe to that event from `Form1`. Inside of the `Form1` event handler method, hide the textbox.

The quick and dirty solution would be to switch to the `ShowDialog` method, which shows another form and blocks execution until that form gets closed. Then you could write:

```
// Create an instance of your Form2 class and show it as a modal dialog
using (var f = new Form2())
{
    f.ShowDialog(this);
}

// When the ShowDialog method returns, the Form2 form has closed, so
// you can go ahead and change the visible state of your control on Form1.
this.TextBox1.Visible = false;
```

However, the disadvantage of modality is that the user cannot interact with `Form1` while `Form2` is open. It's not clear from your question whether or not that is workable. If not, I recommend the previous solution, which involves raising an event. Either way, I highly recommend that you pick up a book on object-oriented programming in C#. Design like this is hard to fix later if you get it wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You can access your parent form using, well, `ParentForm`.

In this case `((Form1)ParentForm).TextBox1.Visible = false;`, assuming `TextBox1` is visible from the outside.

Comment: The title might be a bit deceptive—`Form1` is not the parent of `Form2`. The code he's written doesn't create a parent-child relation. They're two separate top-level windows.

Comment: @CodyGray Hmm seems I misunderstood then.

Comment: +1 because this helped me: It answers the _title_ of the question, which was the first hit on Google when I searched something similar.

Answer (score 2):

On Form2.ClosingEvent

```
Form1 parentForm = Application.OpenForms["FormName"] as Form1;
if (parentForm != null)
 {
    parentForm.TextBox1.Visible = false;
 }
```

make sure that on form1 TextBox1 is public